# How to track Slingshot upload progress change without using setInterval?

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

I am using [meteor-slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot) to upload a file. I want to set the progress bar percentage when it changes.

This is how I do it now.

```
{{percentage}}

percentage: number;
uploadButton() {
  // First start to upload
  // ...

  // Then track the progress
  setInterval(() => {
    this.percentage = uploader.progress();  // The API uploader.progress() returns a number
  }, 1000);
}
```

Is there a smart way using RxJS or something else to track the number change without using `setInterval`?

Thanks

Comment: There's usually an upload progress event available. I'm haven't worked with meteor-slingshot before, but a bit of googling produced [this issue](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/issues/52) that has code that seems to update a progress bar based on the progress events.

Comment: @Ouroborus thank you for giving me a direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uploader.progress()` is a reactive source. So I end up with using `Tracker`.

```
this.autorun(() => this.percentage = uploader.progress());
```